# Url write through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Im working in localhost already wrote the htaccess in my site

Real URL :

```
localhost/lite-cms/template/content/index.php?u_title=about-mind-yolk
```

htaccess that I add

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /lite-cms/template/content/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Im getting the URL like this

```
http://localhost/lite-cms/template/content/about-mind-yolk.html
```

but I want the URL like this without show template/content/

```
http://localhost/lite-cms/about-mind-yolk.html
```

Please give a solution?

Comment: when you access http://localhost/lite-cms/about-mind-yolk.html hwat do you get ?

Comment: Error Message : The requested URL /lite-cms/about-mind-yolk.html was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (make sure the htaccess is in lite-cms/ directory):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /lite-cms/
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ template/content/index.php?u_title=$1 [L]
```

Comment: If I use that in lite-cms/ directory the page will go to always content folder, I have more pages thats what im using the template/content/ directory..

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean, your htaccess currently is where ?

Comment: I have a dynamic Menu , and the URL links also depends thats what I use tha htacess for each directory...

Comment: Links are like this   <br/>   http://localhost/lite-cms/template/content/about-mind-yolk.html     <br/>        http://localhost/lite-cms/template/gallery/about-mind-erer.html <br/>          http://localhost/lite-cms/template/article/about-mind-erfew.html          http://localhost/lite-cms/template/sports/about-mind-sdfgsdfg.html

Comment: you can't ask the htaccess in template/content to rewrite urls like : `http://localhost/lite-cms/about-mind-yolk.html` , since it is not readed, it has to be either in your root directory or in lite-cms directory